# How to run Postgres as a service in gitlab job using own runner?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to configure the gitlab pipeline to run my integration tests against a Postgres DB using Maven. I tried following this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html) but afterwards I noticed that this works only with the shared gitlab runners but I am using my own gitlab runner which runs in Kubernetes.

My `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  untracked: true
  paths:
  - .m2/repository/

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml "
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository/"
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner

stages:
- build
- verify

build:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script:
  - "mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS --quiet clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - "target/*"

test:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
  services:
  - postgres:latest
  stage: verify
  script:
  - "mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS --quiet -Dspring.profiles.active=dev clean test"
```

Using a shared runner this configuration works fine, but I have to use the runner from Kubernetes. Is there any way to execute my tests against a postgres DB without using the shared runner?

Comment: What error do you receive? I suggest you implement your postgres as a k8s deployment and trigger it when required and remove it after the test has run. This is much more k8s style than installing postgres inside the running gitlab runner pod.

Comment: `postgres host is not found`, when my tests try to connect to it. But I see even from the logs that no service is being deployed when using my own runner. Thanks for the suggestion, I thought to ask once here, hoping that there is a way to do this somehow like it works with the gitlab shared runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're hitting a difference in the way network is handled on docker executor and on Kubernetes executor.

The docker executor work pretty much like a `docker-compose` upping all your containers in the same network. **Each container get an IP and a DNS is created**: if your service is named `postgres` the command `nc postgres` will resolve the postgres container IP and contact it (`172.17.0.15:5432` for example).

The kubernetes executor will create a pod runner. All your containers will start in the same pod with only one IP address. **Network between containers in the same pod is done by contacting `127.0.0.1`.** If you want to contact the postgres container you'll likely want to contact `127.0.0.1:5432`. So if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `postgres` it should work.

In order to get your pipeline working on both executors you can either:

- Detect on which kind of runner you're using runner tags `$CI_RUNNER_TAGS`
- Define a custom variable `$POSTGRES_URL` on all your executors
- Try to resolve `postgres` and fall back to 127.0.0.1

Comment: `127.0.0.1:5432` works. Thank you, especially for the perfect description